# How to remove CoreData's objects from memory?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I use CoreData to store image data that user took from iPhone's Camera.  Over time, the memory consumed by these objects keep increasing, but I don't know how to clear those objects from the memory.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell the managedObjectContext to retain or not retain objects (in addition to the ones you retain) with:

```
[managedObjectContext setRetainsRegisteredObjects:YES];
```

See http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html for a discussion of what this does.

Note that you also have to be careful not to retain and leak the objects yourself, or this will have no effect.

-Wil

Comment: Also, you can use [NSManagedObjectContext reset] to wipe all objects from memory and start over in that context. Finally,  NSManagedObjectContext’s refreshObject:mergeChanges: method can be used to clear off the property objects of a given single entity (it turns properties into faults).